# Data store for a cross OS command line tool?

Tags: bash, command-line-interface

Im developing a CLI tool, lets call it `my-command`. When running it with an argument `park` I would like it to save the current directory for later usage.

```
cd /home/me/stuff
my-command park
my-command show-dir
# prints /home/me/stuff
```

How can this be achieved? I suspect there needs to be some environment variable set, or a dedicated folder for the command?

Please see a draft of my code below. Ideally it should work for Linux, mac and window users (though I understand bash scripts might be a problem for windows users.)

```
if ! [ $# -eq 0 ] && [ $1 = "park" ]; then
    echo "Save current directory here"
fi

if ! [ $# -eq 0 ] && [ $1 = "show-dir" ]; then
    echo "Retrieve saved directory here"
fi
```

Comment: Anything that has to persist across multiple processes has to be stored in a file, a database, or in the memory of another long-lived process (for example, a Redis store).

Comment: @chepner, exactly, my question is what would be a good way to implement that? For example with file store, where is a good place to store a command specific file when OS differs among the users?

Comment: How long would you like to keep the directory? Do you mind if that info is lost after you close the terminal?